# Rename tgz files into another names based on a two columns in text file

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed, grep

I have a folder that contains files like this :

```
s-10.tgz  s-11.tgz  s-12.tgz
```

and a text file as follows :

```
s-10 Tom
s-11 Harry 
s-12 Peter
```

How to rename the files to

```
Tom.tgz Harry.tgz Peter.tgz
```

based on the text file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to `read` the file and then do a substring expansion. Only works if there are no spaces in the filenames though.

```
while read line;do echo "${line% *}.tgz" "${line##* }.tgz" ;done < file
s-10.tgz Tom.tgz
s-11.tgz Harry.tgz
s-12.tgz Peter.tgz
```

Replace `echo` with `mv` if everything looks ok.